# How to select checkbox with id Angular2

Tags: jquery, angular, checkbox

I would like to "check" a checkbox based on it's id.

template HTML:

```
div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let optionsList of option.options">
          <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-divider"><input type="checkbox" id="{{optionsList.id}}" value="{{optionsList.id}}">{{optionsList.id}}</div>
          <div class="panel-body">{{optionsList.description}}</div>
        </div>
```

controller component:

```
  foo(selected: number): void {
    this._service.foo(bar, options, selected).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.validation = res;
        if(this.validation.furtherAdditions.length > 0) {
          this.validation.furtherAdditions.forEach(
            option =>
            //'checked' checkbox by id from validation
          );

        }
      },
          error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
```

In other words, I have a bunch of checkbox inputs created dynaamically using ngFor. The data is variable, as it is populated from an API. I have recorded the validation ids (what needs to be 'checked') from the API response, and for each ID, I would like to select it. How would I go about this using angular2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this potential option:

Add this to input checkbox:

```
[selected]="checkIfSelected(optionsList.id)"
```

Then in your component:

```
public checkIfSelected(currentId){
    if(!this.validation) return;
    return this.validation.furtherAdditions.some(id => id == currentId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!